# What is the proper way to incorporate additional packages into Laravel?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I am attempting to integrate this package: https://bitbucket.org/cerbero/oauth/wiki/Home
Also seen her on Packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/cerbero/oauth

The documentation from BitBucket says:

```
Installation

Be sure minimum-stability is set to dev in your composer.json, then run:

composer require cerbero/oauth:2.1.0
```

So I include the package after Laravel like this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "cerbero/oauth": "dev-master"
},
```

Then I run the composer command and get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - Installation request for cerbero/oauth 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by cerbero/oauth[2.1.0].
        - cerbero/oauth 2.1.0 requires google/apiclient 1.0.3-beta -> no matching package found.

    Potential causes:
     - A typo in the package name
     - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
       see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

It states that it also requires google/apiclient. So I go to packagist and get the info and paste it into the *require* section of composer.json. Then another missing dependency pops up so I add that one. The cycle continues for a while. Isn't packagist supposed to handle the dependencies automatically? I am new to packagists but I haven't had issues going through other Laravel tutorials that requires packages. What is the proper way to include this Cerbero package into my application? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Composer does take care of dependencies for you, in your current settings, it tries to resolve all dependencies required for your package `cerbero/oauth`, `google/apiclient` being one of them. However the dependencies tried to resolve into non-stable package, and in your `composer.json` file somewhere, it must have stated

`"minimum-stability": "stable"`

The solution is then pretty clear, according to the error message you see, just set the `minimum-stability` to `dev` instead of `stable`.